# Luffy as a water balloon

Tags: one-piece

We discussed a lot about drowning devil fruit users in a bath - see this question: [Can a Devil Fruit user drown in a bathtub?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/11206/1908).

So now I remembered the fight between Luffy and Crocodile. To have a chance, Luffy drank a lot of water and was like a water ballon. But why didn't this affect his strength?

Does he have to be surrounded by water?

[image: a water-balloon-shaped Luffy]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think he isn't affected, because technically at that time, he isn't **submerged** in water, but the water is rather submerged within him. According to the rule, this should be fine. If it wasn't, Devil Fruit Users would always die of thirst or even die from the water within their own body. This type of water could also be considered **"moving" water**, as it moves constantly with every move you make. The same goes for when Luffy defended Whitebeard against Crocodile at Marineford. At that time he covered himself with water and was still able to move freely, since it would be considered moving water. So unless they are submerged into it, Devil Fruit users can touch water without weakening.

From the [Devil Fruit wiki page](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit).

> With this new power comes a weakness: the sea rejects the new Devil Fruit user and they become helpless while **submerged in water** (or "become a hammer," in Japanese parlance).[2] Oda stated in SBS that Devil Fruit users are susceptible to all types of water, not just seawater. This includes the white sea surrounding Skypiea. He elaborated on this, saying that **"moving" water**, like rain or waves, **does not weaken** Devil Fruit users, while standing water does.

Comment: But they don't have to be completely submerged right? In arlong park luffy is submerged except his head. he still doesn't get his strength back seeing as he needs to resuscitated and the water needs to be pumped out of him

Comment: @Wouter No, a little submersion already drains his energy (eg: when Luffy fell in the well (in the shortcut) in Dressrosa, when he put his hand in the sea at the Fishman arc to save Sanji or attack that fishman). There has been [one exception](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11206/can-a-devil-fruit-user-drown-in-a-bathtub#comment13572_11208), but as I said there, that was just a fanservice moment, instead of an actual loophole.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it was sweet water. Whereas sea water takes away powers, not just any water. He must be ok with swimming pools too.

P.S. There was a question about salt too. But I don't think we should seek deep logic here. Sea and seastone annihilates devil fruits power. simple as that. :) Unless Oda sensei decides that some other staff being dangerous will help the plot rolling.

Comment: Then what about when Luffy attacked Crocodile at Marineford? Since there wasn't much other water around,  didn't he use seawater at that point?

Comment: I am sure there was some sweatwater supplies there too. But as I said - don't read too much into it.

Comment: Unfortunately you made the same mistake I always did.  It is any water... no just salt water.  This was from a statement by Oda.

Answer (score 1):

I had the notion that devil fruit users have to be weary sea water, not just any water. That's why Luffy's power didn't work when an enemy put him into a prison made of sea stone.